# Material-ui: Make Datepicker inclusive

Tags: javascript, datepicker, material-ui

I am using Material-ui Datepicker to allow users to download timed event information from a database ie. all the events between two given dates.  However, at the moment if two bracketing dates are chosen no events for the end date will show up.  For example:  choosing bracketing dates of 4 April and 6 April results in a download of all events from 4 April @00:00 to 6 April @00:00 instead of 6 April @23:59.  Right now, people wanting events from 4 April to 6 April have to choose dates 4 April and 7 April.    Is there a way to make the behaviour align with expectations?

Comment: Can't you just add a day before running the query?

Comment: Already done but it just seems kludgy.  I thought maybe there was an option that I'd missed in the component that would allow the adjustment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that from the component, and there is no reason also. This behaviour should be handled on the application, so don't worry, you are doing it in the right way :)